# Where is the STDOUT and STDERR output of a crontab job

Tags: linux, cron, centos

Does any body know where is the STDOUT and STDERR of a normal crontab job output in CentOS?

I checked the `/var/log/cron` file, but it only record the time and command of a cron job executed, no STDOUT or STDERR content found there.

Comment: See the final section of the [tag:crontab] wiki.

Comment: It is often sent by email

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/122246/how-can-i-view-results-of-my-cron-jobs

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch also note, that unless mail is otherwise setup, mail (including cron output) typically ends up appended to a text file like `/var/mail/<my-user-name>`

Answer (score 2):

Have a look on

/etc/rsyslog.d/

there you should can change loglevel of cron .

```
#cron.*                /var/log/cron.log
```

removing the # = maximum logging

```
cron.err                /var/log/cron.log
```

only error log

Comment: This is for things that log to syslog using the `cron` facility. Which, while it might impact cron jobs, isn't a direct answer to the question (unless the implication is that `cron` logs `stdout` and `stderr` of jobs to syslog using the `cron` facility in which case you should explicitly mention that).

Comment: probably need to run `sudo service crond reload`  after changing this

Answer (score 0):

By default, both STDOUT and STDERR are sent by email, using the sendmail program, to the owner of the crontab or to the $MAILTO environment variable. When there's no output, no email is sent.