# Recover print output from python script run via cron on raspberry

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have been running a python script as a cron job to read data from a serial port via a raspberry pi. The data was supposed to be stored in a database but this did unfortunately not happen due to a bug in my code. However, I did have a print statement of the read-out data in my python code.

Unfortunately, I did not redirect output from the python script in the crontab configuration. Is there any other default place where this output would be logged? Until now the the logging for `/etc/rsyslog.conf` for *cron was commented out but there is a catch-all line that was active and seems to include cron jobs, however I could not find anything in the `/var/log/messages` output [image]

It is hard for me to rerun my experiment and the data lost would be a blow to my research.

Comment: Try looking at this post. You want to read from sys.stdout and print it to a file.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804543/read-subprocess-stdout-line-by-line

Comment: @ericl16384 This shows a solution by changing the python code. Unfortunately my python code has already been executed and I need to obtain the data printed in the past. How would this help?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible, but you can:

1. Try copying it and pasting it to a file
 - Try using CTRL-A, CTRL-C, and to paste it, CTRL-V.
 - Try selecting it manually and then copy-pasting.

2. Take a lot of screenshots
 - You can either do this by hand, or write a script that takes screenshots and scrolls down

Comment: @ericl16384 I am not sure I understand. The solution you linked to starts a new subprocess, right? How would this help with getting output from a script that has already run in the past?

Comment: I am not sure. I am saying, while you try to figure out a solution, you may want to archive the results. If you took a lot of screenshots at regular intervals, you could put them in a file, and then "scroll" down through them. It is not easy recovering text from screenshots, but maybe screenshots is better than nothing, right?
https://datatofish.com/screenshot-python/
```
import pyautogui

myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
myScreenshot.save(r'Path to save screenshot\file name.png')
```
Then just loop and have it use the scroll key to scroll down. I have never used it though...

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I think the screenshot solution will not work, there was no output to the screen since the script was run in the background as a cron job.

Comment: Okay. I think I have no more solutions. I will leave my "code" up in case it helps, though.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28067714

Answer (score 0):

It did not format in the comments so here is some code. I have not run it, because I do not have `pyautogui`, but I hope it will help you archive screenshots of your code. **Test this before you rely on it.**:

```
import pyautogui

saveDir = r"PUT PATH HERE THAT ENDS WITH BACKSLASH --> C:PATH\"
scrollSpeed = 10  # Change this for different scrolling speed
count = 10**2 # Change for different amount of screenshots

for i in range(count):
   myScreenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
   myScreenshot.save(f"{saveDir}screenshot{i}.png")

   pyautogui.scroll(scrollSpeed*-1)
```

Sources:

https://datatofish.com/screenshot-python/
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html